# PHPUnit if exception was thrown then .. else

Tags: php, exception, phpunit

I want to check in my PHPUnit tests if a exception was thrown and if yes, the test should be right and if no do other code:

```
if ($this->expectException(InvalidArgumentException::class))
{
    // Test correct

} else {

     ...
    $this->assertEquals($f1, $f2);
    // Test correct

}
```

How can i handle this?

Comment: Your test is doing too much. Split it in two separate tests: one that expects the exception to be thrown (and there nothing to check for it after it runs the tested code), the other that doesn't expect an exception. As a general rule, if you need to use an `if` of `switch` statement in a test it means you must split the test in two (or more) smaller tests.

Answer (score 0):

You just say:

```
$this->expectException(InvalidArgumentException::class);
```

Then call the code that throws the exception. If by the end of the test no exception was thrown, it will fail.

Comment: so is it not possible to check in the test if there is an exception and if not the test should execute an other code? or should i handle this in two different tests?

Comment: Yes, as pointed out by @axiac, this should be two tests, then.